# R: predictive value of X for a change in Y?

Tags: r, random, intercept, delta, baseline

**UPDATE: lmer-function from the lme4 package may provide an answer.**

10 participants underwent a weight loss programme, like so:

```
mydata<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(140,125,120,115,110,110,110,105,100,90,85,100,140,70,100,
100,140,120,220,190,90,100,120,60,90,110,130,110,120,140,NA,65,110,50,NA,90,120,NA,130,
150,NA,60,NA,45,NA,NA,110,NA,160,NA),nrow=10,dimnames=list(c(1:10),c("IQ","Weight.year.1"
,"Weight.year.2","Weight.year.3","Weight.year.4"))))
```

I wonder if IQ predicts weight loss success.

I should not compute the delta, i.e. `lm((Weight.year.1-Weight.year.4)~IQ,data=mydata)`, since heavier people have more potential to lose weight, and results would be biased. It also fails due to many missings.

One idea is to compute and use the person-specific coefficients, i.e. `sapply(1:10,function(i){lm(t(mydata[i,2:5])~c(1:4))$coefficients[2]})`, which, however, still is related to baseline weight.

I am looking to give it a new try with **random intercepts**, but sadly I do not quite understand how to code this in R.
Does anyone know of code to run such an analysis? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Kindest regards.

Comment: Hmm this question may (also?) be relevant on [Cross Validation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). However, people tend to close questions, if they are too R-specific. In case you cross-post, which is frowned upon but sometimes best in terms of getting answers, please place mutual links.

Answer (score 0):

No statistician here, but can't you take the baseline weight into account by putting that in the model as well?
This is what I came up with, quick'n'dirty:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(140,125,120,115,110,110,110,105,100,90,85,100,140,70,100,
                                     100,140,120,220,190,90,100,120,60,90,110,130,110,120,140,NA,65,110,50,NA,90,120,NA,130,
                                     150,NA,60,NA,45,NA,NA,110,NA,160,NA),nrow=10,dimnames=list(c(1:10),c("IQ","Weight.year.1"
                                                                                                                                ,"Weight.year.2","Weight.year.3","Weight.year.4"))))

newdata <- mydata %>%
gather("period", "weight", -IQ) %>%
mutate(period = gsub("Weight.year.", "", period) %>% as.integer()) %>%
full_join(mydata, by = "IQ")

lm( weight ~ IQ + Weight.year.1 + period, data = newdata ) %>% summary()
```

This results in:

> Call:
>   lm(formula = weight ~ IQ + Weight.year.1 + period, data = newdata)
>
> Residuals:
>       Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
>   -43.978 -14.248   0.136  13.100  47.484
>
> Coefficients:
>                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
>   (Intercept)   150.79400   52.30548   2.883  0.00602 ** 
>   IQ             -0.70584    0.39301  -1.796  0.07921 .
>   Weight.year.1   0.45839    0.09481   4.835 1.59e-05 ***
>
> ### period         -8.53867    2.97500  -2.870  0.00623 **
>
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘***’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 21.03 on 45 degrees of freedom
>     (15 observations deleted due to missingness)
>   Multiple R-squared:  0.6019,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.5753 
>   F-statistic: 22.68 on 3 and 45 DF,  p-value: 4.286e-09